# Magento 2 Access Denied while accessing images from Amazone s3 non-public bucket

Tags: magento2, image-upload, aws

I want to upload and access all my images through Amazon s3 bucket. 
My bucket is a non-public bucket and for that, I uploaded images in the bucket successfully. 
but now I want to access that images on my website but it is giving me AccessDenied error and 403(forbidden) error, even though I can't access that images from my bucket. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1AVA.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r0gx.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt5Dp.png

I tried many solutions for this but I didn't get any luck. 
I also added a bucket policy to my bucket.

```
{
    "Version": "2023-03-03",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1679489443842",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

but still, I can't be able to access images. 
Any one has a solution for this then please let me know. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to go to Permissions tab and uncheck Block all public access. Then in the properties tab of the bucket there is an option called 'Static Website Hosting'. You need to enable it and set configurations. In my case, I used 'Redirect Request' and set the url path as 'http://bucket-name.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'

Then, I checked select all box to select all the individual static files and in Actions I selected 'Make Public'

This helped me to load my static files in Django Project.

My CORS code is:

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "POST",
        "GET",
        "PUT"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
}
```

]

My Bucket Policy is:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "ExamplePolicy01",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/bucket"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But I don't want to make it public.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-control-block-public-access.html
here is a link that AWS stopped supporting public access after April 2023.
so I want to access images on non-public bucket.
If you know answer for that so please let me know.
Thanks